# Datatable not load data from json

Tags: jquery, datatable

I am trying load Json data into data table but not loade

Please find below data table code

```
function loadItemDetails(jsonData ) {
    $('#itemsDetails').DataTable( {
        mData: jsonData ,
        columns: [
            { data: "netAmount" }
        ]
    } );
```

In HTML table code :

```
           <table class="table" id="itemsDetails">
                        <thead class="table-head">
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">Sr. No.</th>
                                <th scope="col">Qty</th>
                                <th scope="col">Net Amount</th>
                                <th scope="col">Promo</th>
                                <th scope="col">CB</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                    </table>
```

Json Data :

```
var jsonData = [{"netAmount":"20"},{"netAmount":"20"},{"netAmount":"20"}];
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug 'jsonData' variable? If yes, please provide it as hardcoded value

Comment: Hardcoded means?

Comment: Provide value which you are expecting

Comment: Provide hardcoded data but still not loaded. Do I need to initialize?

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert json in json object as below:

```
jsonData = JSON.stringify(jsonData);
```

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you used `mData` instead of `data`.

```js
function loadItemDetails(jsonData) {
    $('#itemsDetails').DataTable( {
        data: jsonData,
        columns: [
            { data: null },
            { data: null },
            { data: "netAmount" }
        ]
    })
}

loadItemDetails([{"netAmount":"20"},{"netAmount":"20"},{"netAmount":"20"}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table" id="itemsDetails">
  <thead class="table-head">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Sr. No.</th>
      <th scope="col">Qty</th>
      <th scope="col">Net Amount</th>
      <th scope="col">Promo</th>
      <th scope="col">CB</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
var jsonData =  [{"netAmount":"20"},{"netAmount":"20"},{"netAmount":"20"}];
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        data : jsonData,
        "columns": [
            { "data": "netAmount" },

        ]
    } );
} );
```

Here is [working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/a98m37k2/)

Just keep a note on Datatable version